# HTMLPurifier - Change attribute value instead of remove

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

`htmlpurifier` removes attributes if value is not allowed. For example;

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I set the permissions for div tags for `contenteditable` attribute, so the value can be only `false`. But if `contenteditable="true"` or anything other than `false`, `htmlpurifier` totally removes the attribute. I don't like this behavior. I would like to have `htmlpurifier` always keep the `contenteditable` attribute and set it to `false`.

Is this a possibility?

**Actual Configs**

```
$config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'div[contenteditable]');
$config->set('HTML.TargetNoopener', false);
$config->set('HTML.TargetNoreferrer', false);

$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('div', 'contenteditable', 'Enum#false');
```

**Result with this configs**

*Input:*

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

*Output:*

```
<div></div>
```

**Desired Results**

*Input:*

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

*Output:*

```
<div contenteditable="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to change an attribute's handling to coercing a known-good value as opposed to just dropping the bad value. You may need to write an attribute transformation; something like this:

```
class HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_ContentEditable extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('contenteditable', $attr)) {
            $attr['contenteditable'] = 'true';
        }
        return $attr;
    }
}
```

Using/installing the class:

```
$htmlDef = $htmlPurifierConfiguration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$tag     = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('div');
$tag->attr_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_ContentEditable();
// purify down here
```